# Convert List of Tuples to JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of tuple with 50 records which look something like below:

```
tuple_list = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,3,2),(4,3,1),(8,6,5)]
```

I want to be able to convert it to a JSON format which looks something like this:
json = `[{ link: 1, title: 2, desc:3},{ link: 2, title: 3, desc: 4},{ link: 5, title: 3, desc:2},{ link: 4, title: 3, desc: 1},{ link: 8, title: 6, desc:5}]`

I tried converting it to the dictionary and then to JSON, directly dumping it to JSON but I am getting errors.
Can someone point me to how to do it?

Methods I tried:
1.

```
import json
lst = [("name", "value"), ("name2", "value2")]
rs = json.dumps(dict(lst))
print(rs)
```

2. Converted it to Dataframe and tried to put to JSON

   df.to_json('temp.json', orient='records', lines=True)

Comment: What is the exact JSON output you are expecting here?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. Also, try to solve a smaller problem first. Given `(1,2,3)`, can you write code that creates the corresponding dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you framed the question correctly or used the right phrases, but if you are trying to convert the tuple to a dictionary, there are multiple ways. A one liner approach would be

```
my_dict = [dict(zip(("link", "title", "desc"), x)) for x in tuple_list]
print(my_dict)
```

which gives

```
[{'link': 1, 'title': 2, 'desc': 3}, {'link': 2, 'title': 3, 'desc': 4}, {'link': 5, 'title': 3, 'desc': 2}, {'link': 4, 'title': 3, 'desc': 1}, {'link': 8, 'title': 6, 'desc': 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `dict` comprehension:

```
{k:v for (k,v) in lst}
```

Output

```
{'name': 'value', 'name2': 'value2'}
```

Can then convert to `json`, using `json.dumps`